# How to pass AngularUI Google Map object to a factory or request transformation?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs, angular-ui, factories

I have a REST service that returns geo-coordinates that I'm consuming with a factory using `$http` in AngularJS. In order to display these coordinates as markers, I need to create `google.maps.Marker` object which take both a position and a `google.maps.Map` object.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do these data transformations either in the factory, or as part of a `transformResponse`. Unfortunately, the AngularUI maps directive that I'm using stores the map on the local scope.

What is the best way to supply the `Map` object to either the factory or transformResponse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're adamant about your geocoordinates service returning `Marker`s instead of geocoordinates, then you have two options that I can think of:

a) Pass the map to the geocoordinates service

```
angular.module('mapGuy', function($scope, geoService) {
  geoService.addMarkers($scope.map);
}).
factory('geoService', function($http) {
  var addMarkers = function(map) {
    $http.get('/path/to/geo/server').success(function(points) {
      angular.forEach(points, function(points) {
        new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map, position: new google.maps.LatLng(points.lat, points.long)
        })
      })
    });
  };

  return { addMarkers: addMarkers };
});
```

b) Stick the map on the module's `$rootScope` and inject `$rootScope` into the service

```
angular.module('mapGuy', function($scope, $rootScope, geoService) {
  $rootScope.map = $scope.map;
  geoService.addMarkers();
}).
factory('geoService', function($http, $rootScope) {
  var addMarkers = function() {
    $http.get('/path/to/geo/server').success(function(points) {
      angular.forEach(points, function(points) {
        new google.maps.Marker({
          map: $rootScope.map, position: new google.maps.LatLng(points.lat, points.long)
        })
      })
    });
  };

  return { addMarkers: addMarkers };
});
```

That's a rough sketch of what the code could look like. I'm pulling Google Maps API from memory, but hopefully this helps you get the idea.

I think the first option is preferable, but it's hard to say since you didn't provide a lot of context to work with.

Comment: Option B is what I originally did, but it seemed "forced" or non-functional. Option A gives me something to think about.